Restrict domain of plots with data coming from different files
I would like to plot some data where the x axis values come from one file and the y axis values come from another file. However, I also want to restrict the domain of the plotted data. For example, consider the following MWE
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{p.txt}
0   0
0.1 -0.33075
0.2 -0.57921
0.3 -0.70349
0.4 -0.71557
0.5 -0.5749
0.6 -0.28143
0.7 0.074107
0.8 0.39911
0.9 0.6013
1.  0.6732
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{q.txt}
0   0.7854
0.1 0.68345
0.2 0.43306
0.3 0.15228
0.4 -0.15205
0.5 -0.51178
0.6 -0.77854
0.7 -0.81509
0.8 -0.62097
0.9 -0.32121
1.  -0.084097
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/Y/.style={
        create col/copy column from table={p.txt}{1}
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [restrict x to domain=0:1,x index=1, y=Y] {q.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

It plots the second column of the second file against the second column of the first file.
I would like restrict the plot so that only values that correspond to the domain [0:0.5] in the first column of q.txt or p.txt are plotted. The following would be the desired output.

This would correspond to the plot generated with the following code
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{p.txt}
0   0
0.1 -0.33075
0.2 -0.57921
0.3 -0.70349
0.4 -0.71557
0.5 -0.5749
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{q.txt}
0   0.7854
0.1 0.68345
0.2 0.43306
0.3 0.15228
0.4 -0.15205
0.5 -0.51178
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/Y/.style={
        create col/copy column from table={p.txt}{1}
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x index=1, y=Y] {q.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Of course I do not want to manually modify each one of my source files. Can this be achieved?
I tried adding the instruction restrict x to domain=0:0.5, however this instruction is affected by the x index=1 option and does not result in the required plot (see the image below).


I don't understand why the output produced with \begin{axis}[restrict x to domain=0:0.5] doesn't correspond to the desired one?

@jlab Because the option x index=1 makes it so that the x axis now corresponds to the second column of q.txt. Otherwise the instruction would work.

x means the value used for the x axis. You can use \thisrow{0} to add a filter on the first column
x filter/.code={
  \pgfmathparse{ \thisrow{0} >= 0 && \thisrow{0} <= 0.5 ? x : nan }
},

By the way the package filecontents is obsolete, its functionalities are now provided by the LaTeX kernel. It's also better to set a compatibility version for pgfplots with \pgfplotsset{compat=<version>}.
Full example:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{filecontents}{p.txt}
0   0
0.1 -0.33075
0.2 -0.57921
0.3 -0.70349
0.4 -0.71557
0.5 -0.5749
0.6 -0.28143
0.7 0.074107
0.8 0.39911
0.9 0.6013
1.  0.6732
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{q.txt}
0   0.7854
0.1 0.68345
0.2 0.43306
0.3 0.15228
0.4 -0.15205
0.5 -0.51178
0.6 -0.77854
0.7 -0.81509
0.8 -0.62097
0.9 -0.32121
1.  -0.084097
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/Y/.style={
        create col/copy column from table={p.txt}{1}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      x filter/.code={
        \pgfmathparse{ \thisrow{0} >= 0 && \thisrow{0} <= 0.5 ? x : nan }
      },
    ]
  \addplot table [x index=1, y=Y] {q.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


